# "nLab-style" website for Riemannian Geometry and/or Geometric Analysis

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, online-resources

I really like the nLab and its collaborative style of writing. 
Are there any other websites which follow the same philosophy, but on different topics, or with different points of view?

For example, is there one more on the metric aspects of Riemannian Geometry, Geometric Analysis, Harmonic Analysis and the like?

Answer (score 8):

All these subjects (Riemannian geometry, harmonic analysis etc.) are squarely on-topic for the $n$Lab. Currently there are not too many contributors actively writing about these topics, but that's just for lack of volunteers, not out of principle. Every serious contribution which you may have will be welcome, and is likely to eventually attract more interested people.

(Notice that he $n$Lab is not at all restricted to discussion of category theory, instead it is about discussion of mathematics, physics and philosophy broadly. The language of category theory is encouranged as the ideal tool for organizing mathematics on broad scales, seeing parallels and analogies between different branches.)